# Remove subroute from express middleware

Tags: express, routes, authorization, nodejs-server, express-router

I have NodeJs App in which i am using a middleware for authorization which is as follows:-

```
app.use('/api', authorizeMiddleWare, routes);
```

and there is routes which consists of all the routes which is suppose as follows:-

```
router.use('/route1', route1);
router.use('/route2', route2);
```

and these routes also have sub routes

```
router.route('/:id/user').get(controller.getUser)
```

> I want to exclude only this Route from authorization middleware:-

***GET /api/route1/id/user***

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by modifying the authorizationMiddleware and doing regex match on the particular API